# Variable value returns null after assigning value inside geocoder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting that latValue null when i print, does anyone have clue how i can get that value outside that geocoder

```
     var latValue = ""
     var longValue = ""
     
     geocoder.geocodeAddressString("yagoona,nsw") {
         placemarks, error in
         let placemark = placemarks?.first
         let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
         let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
        
         latValue = String(lat ?? 0)
         longValue = String(lon ?? 0)
       
        print("add lat:",latValue)
        print("add long:",longValue)
         
         
     }
     print("address latitude:  ",latValue)
```

Comment: `geocodeAddressString(_:completion:)` is asynchrone. It uses a closure to notice when the asynchrone call is done. So use the same logic, use a closure to manage that.

Comment: i am new to this. do you have any example to show